# Error in Installing Prerequisites of Sharepoint Server 2010

Tags: 2010, installation

I'm installing Sharepoint Server 2010 and before that it requires prerequisites to install. It is skipping the installation of KB976462 & KB974405 (which I tried installing seprately but no luck) plus I have restarted the machine several times but the Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role is throwing some configuration error.

Below is the summary of prerequisties

• **Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role**: configuration error - pending restart of the computer 
• Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client: was already installed (no action taken) 
• **Hotfix for Microsoft Windows (KB976462): Installation skipped** 
• **Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405): Installation skipped** 
• Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64): equivalent products already installed (no action taken) 
• Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5: was already installed (no action taken) 
• Microsoft Filter Pack 2.0: equivalent products already installed (no action taken) 
• **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services ADOMD.NET**: Installation skipped 
• Microsoft Server Speech Platform Runtime (x64): Installation skipped (optional component) 
• Microsoft Server Speech Recognition Language - TELE(en-US): Installation skipped(optional component) 
• SQL 2008 R2 Reporting Services SharePoint 2010 Add-in: Installation skipped (optional component)

The installations marked bold are behaving in an unexpected way.

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: Any comments????

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Sounds like your application server role is in a corrupt state.  Can you try to configure it manually and see if that gets you any further?

Comment: I am using Win Server 2008 R2. I have tried configuring manually as well as using prerequistie file too. is just DOESN'T WORK!!! Plus the hotfix say that "there is no update available for the selected computer" I am using x64 machine

Comment: When I'm tryn to install Hotfixes it says that the "The update is not applicable to your system". Error can be view at http://imageshack.us/a/img145/1180/sphotfixerror.png

Comment: your machine is misconfigured ('hosed') somehow.  You need to either fix the problem or rebuild the machine from scratch and start over.

Comment: @DerekGusoff: I have rebuild the machine from scratch and done the prerequisties installation like hundred times. Everytime the hotfixes seems to gave me the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar issue by ending the IIS-ManagementService (? - in German IISVerwaltungsdienst) and WWW-PublishingService befor the Setup.

I guess, that the "Installation skipped" notifications just say, that the Setup didn't try because of the other error.

Answer (score -1):

go to `windows\system32` directory.

then just make duplication for the `servermanager.ex`e and then rename to `servermanagercmd.exe`